# Cuda Thrust String or Char Sort

Tags: c++, c, cuda, thrust

I am trying to sort string with cuda thrust .

I found a sample on this link
https://github.com/bzip2-cuda/bzip2-cuda/blob/master/tst/string_sort_try0.cu

when i try to compile i get the following error message. What can I do to fix it?

`"Error 1   error : **no instance of overloaded function "thrust::pointer<Element, Tag, Reference, Derived>::operator= [with Element=char, Tag=thrust::device_system_tag, Reference=thrust::device_reference<char>, Derived=thrust::device_ptr<char>]" matches the argument list**  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include\thrust\device_ptr.h 109 1   CharSort "`

a part of code block is

```
class device_string
{
public:
    int cstr_len;
    char* raw;
    thrust::device_ptr<char> cstr;

    static char* pool_raw;
    static thrust::device_ptr<char> pool_cstr;
    static thrust::device_ptr<char> pool_top;

    // Sets the variables up the first time its used.
    __host__ static void init()
    {
                static bool v = true;
            if( v )
            {
                    v = false;

                    pool_cstr = thrust::device_malloc(POOL_SZ);
                    pool_raw  = (char*)raw_pointer_cast( pool_cstr );
                    pool_top = pool_cstr;
            }
    }
    // Destructor for device variables used.
```

Comment: thrust has changed a lot since **2 years ago**

Answer (score 3):

You can work around that particular issue by changing this line of code:

```
                pool_cstr = thrust::device_malloc(POOL_SZ);
```

to this:

```
                pool_cstr = thrust::device_malloc<char>(POOL_SZ);
```

But as @Eric indicates, once you fix that you will run into other issues trying to compile this code.

**EDIT:** Actually the remaining problems appear to be all warnings, and an executable is produced which seems to run correctly (with the above fix).